# Overbrace Inside Underbrace

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I would like to have an overbrace inside an underbrace (not overlapping braces).  Here is an equation I have been trying:

```
    \begin{equation}
    \max_{a \in A} \left\{\underbrace{ \left(v_a + v_y y \right) a - C(a)}_{\text{blabla}}
    \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{v_y y ) a - C(a)}}^{\text{blablabla}}}
    + \mu_a \mathbb{E}(v_a | a, y) - \mu_y \mathbb{E}(v_y|a,y)\right\}.
    \end{equation}
```

So far, I am obtaining an overbrace shifted far to the right:

[image]

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full minimal example. Not everyone know that `\mathclap` comes from `mathtools`

Comment: And what exactly is the overbrace suppose to cover? `a-C(a)`?

Comment: then just use `\underbrace{ ... \overbrace{...}^{A}}_{B}` just tested, works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that gets by without `\mathrlap`. Note also the declaration of `\E` as a "math operator", the use of `\mid` instead of `|` (in order to obtain some whitespace on both sides of the vertical bars), and the use of `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` instead of `\left\{` and `\right\}` (to avoid getting unnecessarily large curly braces).

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\[
    \max_{a \in A}
    \biggl\{
    \underbrace{ ( v_a + \overbrace{v_y y ) a - C(a)}^{ \text{blabla}}}_{\text{blabla}}
    {} + \mu_a \E(v_a \mid  a, y) - \mu_y \E(v_y\mid a,y)
    \biggr\}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is is just me, or is the spacing around the `+` after the `\underbrace` wrong/missing?

Comment: @daleif - Good catch! I'll modify the code to insert `{}` before `+` in order to change its type from unary to binary operator.

Comment: Egreg recommends adding a brace around the whole thing instead. `\underbrace` is an Op atom.

Comment: @daleif - egreg's recommendation is certainly sound *in general*. In the present case, though, the term immediately before the `+` symbol is rather dominant visually, as it ends with an overbrace, a parenthesis, *and* and an underbrace. Using the `{}`-before`+` approach provides just a teeny bit more whitespace ahead of the `+` symbol, letting the entire equation look a bit more balanced. :-)

Answer (score 0):

After a while, I got it:

```
    \begin{equation}
    \max_{a \in A} \left\{
    \underbrace{ (v_a + 
    \mathrlap{\overbrace{\phantom{v_y y ) a - C(a)}}^{\text{blablabla}}}
    v_y y ) a - C(a)}_{\text{blabla}}
    + \mu_a \mathbb{E}(v_a | a, y) - \mu_y \mathbb{E}(v_y|a,y)\right\}.
    \end{equation}
```